# Formatted input box in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, formatted-input, maked-textbox

Is there a control or method to accept formatted input in VB.NET?

i.e. It accepts input in a given format ##/##/## or similar?

Answer (score 3):

You want the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

sure there is :)

and a pretty good/nice one, [for asp.net](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) and [for winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx